# How much beef and seafood should I buy for mixed 12 adult dinner party?

Tags: roast-beef

serving Boneless Beef Rib Roast, scallops {U/12 size} , Shrimp [16-21 size} with Alfredo pasta. All have good appetites; beef roast will be most popular then  shrimp. Plz suggest how much to plan for each person. Thanks...sm

Comment: What else are you serving? Sides? appetizers? Is this the only thing going on the plates?

Comment: I sure hope meal planning is out of scope

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb for a standard dinner is:

- 250g of protein
- 200g of carbohydrates
- 200g of vegetables

*for a man* and:

- 200g of protein
- 180g of carbohydrates
- 200g of vegetables

*for a woman.*

But for a small dinner (<50 people) cook for one more person than is attending.
<sub>(Better be safe than sorry)</sub>

As you're having a dinner *party* (which normally takes longer than a standard dinner) add 33% overall for *an extended dinner party*, which brings us to:

- 4 Kg of protein (8.5 pounds, to be split between Beef / Shrimp / Scallops)
- 3 Kg of carbohydrates (7.2 pounds)
- 3.5 Kg of vegetables (7.6 pounds)

for 6 women and 7 men for an extended dinner party. (13 total: one more than you need)

<sub>**Note:** Feel free to recalculate according to your needs.  (E.G. if you have appetizers, soup, starter, dessert as well, *don't use the 33% at all*)

**P.S.** Sorry, but I cannot calculate in [Imperial mass units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Iv8.jpg), though I can convert the end result...  **0:-)**</sub>

Answer (score 1):

With meats, the general rule of thumb is 1 pound per dinner guest, especially when using a whole roast, turkey, or something similar that requires carving. Assume 2 scallops per person on average, as not everyone will be interested in this type of shellfish.

As for shrimp, I always refer to the table found on this page: https://farmtotableasiansecrets.wordpress.com/2007/12/17/medium-large-jumbo-colossal/
as it has always been accurate for me in the past. Thus, for your size, I would suggest an average of 5 shrimp per person.

Hope your dinner party goes well!